# Family started teasing me recently…

Tags: weight-loss, bodyweight-exercises, weight-gain, fat, bodyweight

As of recently my family have began teasing me telling me I’ve gained quite a bit of weight over the last two years. I hadn’t noticed up now that I might if gained a little weight. For reference I’ve linked some photos of me from around two years ago up until yesterday. The first photo however is an outlier as I know I’ve gained weight since then as I was far too skinny and wanted to be a little thicker. Have I really got fat or are they being picky?

https://ibb.co/jLNTbGV
https://ibb.co/kHDjD3g
https://ibb.co/w0ZKr1z
https://ibb.co/G2CbJHg